# Removing namespace declaration using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, ibm-datapower

My requirement is to remove the namespace declaration from the the input xml using xslt, if certain condition is true.

I have went through various forums in stackoverflow, after that I had managed to build up an xsl, but it still is not working. I am pretty new to xsl and hence need an help here to achieve this.

input xml (Namespace declaration is appearing)

```
           <?xml version="1.0"?>
              <message xmlns="http://www.origoservices.com"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.origoservices.com CEBondRealTimeValuationResponse.XSD">
             <m_control>
              <control_timestamp>2015-11-18T12:15:00</control_timestamp>
               <message_id>428f7945-a3d8-49f8-ada3-b6e898ace9fe</message_id>
    <retry_number>0</retry_number>
    <message_type>test</message_type>
<message_version>test</message_version>
<message_status>Success</message_status>
<expected_response_type>synchronous</expected_response_type>
<initiator_id>Testing</initiator_id>
<responder_id>Test-comp</responder_id>
 </m_control>
     <m_content>
         <b_control>
    <contract_enquiry_reference/>
    <enquiry_response_status>Error</enquiry_response_status>
    <enquiry_error_note code="1005" sequence_number="1">
        <short_description>Contract not found.</short_description>
    </enquiry_error_note>
</b_control>
<intermediary/>
<request_scope>
    <valuation_request type="Current"/>
    <valuation_request type="Surrender"/>
    <fund_breakdown_request>
        <detailed_breakdown_ind>Yes</detailed_breakdown_ind>
    </fund_breakdown_request>
</request_scope>
<contract>
    <contract_reference_number>20015</contract_reference_number>
</contract>
   </m_content>
     </message>
```

Expected output: (Should be without `http://www.origoservices.com` and other namespace declaration must be preserved )

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.origoservices.com CEBondRealTimeValuationResponse.XSD">
         <m_control>
             <control_timestamp>2015-11-18T12:15:00</control_timestamp>
    <message_id>428f7945-a3d8-49f8-ada3-b6e898ace9fe</message_id>
    <retry_number>0</retry_number>
    <message_type>test</message_type>
    <message_version>test</message_version>
    <message_status>Success</message_status>
    <expected_response_type>synchronous</expected_response_type>
    <initiator_id>Testing</initiator_id>
    <responder_id>Test-comp</responder_id>
</m_control>
<m_content>
    <b_control>
        <contract_enquiry_reference/>
        <enquiry_response_status>Error</enquiry_response_status>
        <enquiry_error_note code="1005" sequence_number="1">
            <short_description>Contract not found.</short_description>
        </enquiry_error_note>
    </b_control>
    <intermediary/>
    <request_scope>
        <valuation_request type="Current"/>
        <valuation_request type="Surrender"/>
        <fund_breakdown_request>
            <detailed_breakdown_ind>Yes</detailed_breakdown_ind>
        </fund_breakdown_request>
    </request_scope>
    <contract>
        <contract_reference_number>20015</contract_reference_number>
    </contract>
</m_content>
   </message>
```

I have tried below xslt:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp">
          <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" /> 
         <xsl:variable name="origo-svc-augmented" select="'Y'"/>  
      <xsl:variable name="origo-svc-ns" select="'http://www.origoservices.com'" /> 
      <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:variable name="namespace" select="namespace-uri(.)" /> 
          <xsl:choose>
              <!-- 
          xsl:when test="$namespace = ''
                  or ($origo-svc-augmented='Y' and $namespace=$origo-svc-ns)"

         --> 
               <xsl:when test="$origo-svc-augmented = 'Y'">
                   <xsl:message dp:type="business-log" dp:priority="info">Namespace was augmented in the request rule</xsl:message> 
                <!-- Note: If we use "local-name()" instead of "name()" in below statement, then namespace prefixes will not be preserved. Using name(), will preserve the namespace prefixes
                  --> 
             <!-- xsl:element name="{name()} namespace="{$namespace}"
          --> 
                  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
               <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(namespace-uri()=$origo-svc-ns)]" /> 
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|comment()|processing-instruction()|text()" /> 
               </xsl:element>
              </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$namespace}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*" /> 
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|comment()|processing-instruction()|text()" /> 
        </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()|text()">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|comment()|processing-instruction()|text()" /> 
      </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried to combine both the answers and able to find the solution for this. Please find the working XSLT below.

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp">
       <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>

       <xsl:variable name="origo-svc-augmented" select="'Y'"/>
       <xsl:variable name="origo-svc-ns" select="'http://www.origoservices.com'"/>

      <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:variable name="namespace" select="namespace-uri(.)"/>
         <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="($origo-svc-augmented = 'Y') and (namespace-uri() = $origo-svc-ns)">
            <xsl:message dp:type="business-log" dp:priority="info">Namespace was augmented in the request rule</xsl:message>
             <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[.!='http://www.origoservices.com']"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates
                select="@* | node() | comment() | processing-instruction() | text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
         </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$namespace}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="@* | node() | comment() | processing-instruction() | text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
      </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: *"My requirement is to remove the namespace declaration from the the input xml using xslt, if certain condition is true"*. What is the condition?

Comment: And would like to remove all namespaces declarations? What are we supposed to do with the `xsi` and the `ds` namespaces (this latter being unused in your XML)?

Comment: @har07  I only want to remove the namespace related to the origoservices.com. when `$origo-svc-augmented = 'Y'`

Answer (score 2):

It's important to understand that in terms of the XDM data model, what you are doing is not *removing a namespace*, but rather *changing the name of the element*.

Unless you have QNames (or namespace prefixes) appearing within the content of your elements or attributes (as opposed to their names), you shouldn't need to worry about using the namespace axis or generating namespace nodes. Just generate elements and attributes with the correct names (by which I mean namespace URI plus local name) and the namespace declarations will take care of themselves.

The `xsl:copy` instruction, when applied to an element, copies the whole name (namespace URI plus local name) of the element. If you want to generate an element with the same local name but in a different namespace, or in no namespace, you need to use `xsl:element name="{local-name()}"`

You've had plenty of responses suggesting what code you need to write, but I thought it would be helpful to add a word on the underlying principles.

Answer (score 1):

If I am guessing correctly, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="no-namespace" select="false()"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$no-namespace">
            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[.!='http://www.origoservices.com']"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[.!='http://www.origoservices.com']"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the `no-namespace` parameter is true, the result, applied to your input example, will **probably** (see note below) be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.origoservices.com CEBondRealTimeValuationResponse.XSD">
   <m_control>
      <control_timestamp>2015-11-18T12:15:00</control_timestamp>
      <message_id>428f7945-a3d8-49f8-ada3-b6e898ace9fe</message_id>
      <retry_number>0</retry_number>
      <message_type>test</message_type>
      <message_version>test</message_version>
      <message_status>Success</message_status>
      <expected_response_type>synchronous</expected_response_type>
      <initiator_id>Testing</initiator_id>
      <responder_id>Test-comp</responder_id>
   </m_control>
   <m_content>
      <b_control>
         <contract_enquiry_reference/>
         <enquiry_response_status>Error</enquiry_response_status>
         <enquiry_error_note code="1005" sequence_number="1">
            <short_description>Contract not found.</short_description>
         </enquiry_error_note>
      </b_control>
      <intermediary/>
      <request_scope>
         <valuation_request type="Current"/>
         <valuation_request type="Surrender"/>
         <fund_breakdown_request>
            <detailed_breakdown_ind>Yes</detailed_breakdown_ind>
         </fund_breakdown_request>
      </request_scope>
      <contract>
         <contract_reference_number>20015</contract_reference_number>
      </contract>
   </m_content>
</message>
```

If the `no-namespace` parameter is false, the result will be an identical copy of the input.

---

**Note:**

The actual result may wary according to the specific XSLT processor being used. The namespace declaration `xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"` is not used anywhere, and is therefore redundant. You cannot really force an XSLT 1.0 processor to output a redundant namespace declaration. The above result is correct for Saxon 6.5 and libxslt - but Xalan will ignore the instruction to copy namespaces and the redundant namespace *will* be suppressed.

Comment: Provided an update to the question with the working XSLT

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to remove the namespace related to the `http://www.origoservices.com` URI, I would change the condition a namespace removal to:

```
 <xsl:when test="($origo-svc-augmented = 'Y') and (namespace-uri() = $origo-svc-ns)">
```

and then output the element like so, to avoid copying the namespaces:

```
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
```

Copying the namespace nodes with `<xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(namespace-uri() = $origo-svc-ns)]"/>` become useless, you can drop it.

Then you end up with the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="namespace" select="namespace-uri(.)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="($origo-svc-augmented = 'Y') and (namespace-uri() = $origo-svc-ns)">
            <xsl:message dp:type="business-log" dp:priority="info">Namespace was augmented in the request rule</xsl:message>
            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                <xsl:apply-templates
                    select="@* | node() | comment() | processing-instruction() | text()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$namespace}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates
                    select="@* | node() | comment() | processing-instruction() | text()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the resulting XML obtained:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.origoservices.com CEBondRealTimeValuationResponse.XSD">
    <m_control>
        <control_timestamp>2015-11-18T12:15:00</control_timestamp>
        <message_id>428f7945-a3d8-49f8-ada3-b6e898ace9fe</message_id>
        <retry_number>0</retry_number>
        <message_type>test</message_type>
        <message_version>test</message_version>
        <message_status>Success</message_status>
        <expected_response_type>synchronous</expected_response_type>
        <initiator_id>Testing</initiator_id>
        <responder_id>Test-comp</responder_id>
    </m_control>
    <m_content>
        <b_control>
            <contract_enquiry_reference/>
            <enquiry_response_status>Error</enquiry_response_status>
            <enquiry_error_note code="1005" sequence_number="1">
                <short_description>Contract not found.</short_description>
            </enquiry_error_note>
        </b_control>
        <intermediary/>
        <request_scope>
            <valuation_request type="Current"/>
            <valuation_request type="Surrender"/>
            <fund_breakdown_request>
                <detailed_breakdown_ind>Yes</detailed_breakdown_ind>
            </fund_breakdown_request>
        </request_scope>
        <contract>
            <contract_reference_number>20015</contract_reference_number>
        </contract>
    </m_content>
</message>
```

Since the namespace `xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"` is never used in your input XML document, it won't be output.

Comment: You have guessed it correctly, I only want to remove the namespace related to the http://www.origoservices.com. when `$origo-svc-augmented = 'Y'`   I have tried your code, but in the output, all the namespace declarations are getting removed.

Comment: Provided an update to the question with the working XSLT

Comment: OK, I understand but in IMHO there's no point keeping the `xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"` namespace since it is not used.

Comment: And please consider [adding an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to your question - not as an update to it - and accept it so that the question will be closed (and perhaps adding helpful flags for the questions that helped you). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

have tried to combine both the answers and able to find the solution for this. Please find the working XSLT below.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>

   <xsl:variable name="origo-svc-augmented" select="'Y'"/>
   <xsl:variable name="origo-svc-ns" select="'http://www.origoservices.com'"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="namespace" select="namespace-uri(.)"/>
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="($origo-svc-augmented = 'Y') and (namespace-uri() = $origo-svc-ns)">
        <xsl:message dp:type="business-log" dp:priority="info">Namespace was augmented in the request rule</xsl:message>
         <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[.!='http://www.origoservices.com']"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates
            select="@* | node() | comment() | processing-instruction() | text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
     </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$namespace}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="@* | node() | comment() | processing-instruction() | text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```